# Cant properly add service reference in VS 2012 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, add-references-dialog

I just add address of the service, press GO and ok. After that generated Reference.svcmap looks right, but Reference.cs is empty!

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17626
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And thats all. Cant work with ServiceClient object!
PS: Adding same service reference in VS2010 works ok and reference.cs is fully generated.
The question is: is there is a problem in generating the ClientObject, why VS is not giving me any warning message. Also if someone has experiences such problem-how can i fix that?

**Version information:**
*Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC

Version 11.0.50706.0 QRELRC July, 2012

Microsoft .NET Framework

Version 4.5.50501*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the exact sam problem. I unchecked 3:rd party dll:s like on this page:
[link](http://uliasz.com/2011/06/wcf-custom-tool-error-failed-to-generate-code-for-the-service-reference/)

Comment: This was the EXACT answer I needed.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  To find some information out on exactly what is failing you can go to the ErrorList window and show warnings.  I realized my issue was a property on one of the objects being created was framework specific and 4.0 but my local project was 3.5.  Once I removed the reuse references it generated my code.

Comment: For this answer, I would give you more ups if I could. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Same problem in 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929

Unchecked the "Reuse Types in referenced assemblies" checkbox in the Configure Service reference dialog.

Worked for me:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112960/visual-studio-2012-error-reference-svcmap-throwing-error)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any warnings.
I had this problem once and found a warning regarding a locked dll.
After fixing the warning the reference.cs was created again.