# How to return an object and format it as json?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to return JSON objects with the following controller:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string query)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "NotSoSecret#1", "mydomain"),
        });
        var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("myorgetc.com").ToList()[0];
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/myorg/api/data/v8.1/", ipAddress.ToString()));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress +"accounts"+ query);
        object result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            return Ok(result);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

And it's returning the following exception:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.  An error
>   has occurred.  Type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract
>   which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of
>   collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to
>   itself.  
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
>     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.ValidatePreviousCollectionTypes(Type
>   collectionType, Type itemType, Dictionary`2 previousCollectionTypes)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetNonDCTypeStableName(Type
>   type, Dictionary`2 previousCollectionTypes) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(Type type,
>   Dictionary`2 previousCollectionTypes, Boolean& hasDataContract) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDefaultStableLocalName(Type
>   type) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDCTypeStableName(Type
>   type, DataContractAttribute dataContractAttribute) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetStableName(Type type,
>   Dictionary`2 previousCollectionTypes, Boolean& hasDataContract) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetCollectionStableName(Type
>   type, Type itemType, Dictionary`2 previousCollectionTypes,
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute& collectionContractAttribute) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.CollectionDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type
>   type, CollectionKind kind, Type itemType, MethodInfo
>   getEnumeratorMethod, String serializationExceptionMessage, String
>   deserializationExceptionMessage) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.CollectionDataContractCriticalHelper..ctor(Type
>   type, CollectionKind kind, Type itemType, MethodInfo
>   getEnumeratorMethod, MethodInfo addMethod, ConstructorInfo
>   constructor) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract..ctor(Type type,
>   CollectionKind kind, Type itemType, MethodInfo getEnumeratorMethod,
>   MethodInfo addMethod, ConstructorInfo constructor, Boolean
>   isConstructorCheckRequired) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.IsCollectionOrTryCreate(Type
>   type, Boolean tryCreate, DataContract& dataContract, Type& itemType,
>   Boolean constructorRequired, Boolean skipIfReadOnlyContract) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.GetDataContract(DataContract
>   declaredTypeContract, Type declaredType, Type objectType) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter
>   writer, Object graph) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.d__13.MoveNext()

**What am I doing wrong? How do I return a JSON object without knowing the exact structure at dev time?**

Here is my startup:

```
public static class Startup
    {
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.

        public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IAccountsRepository, AccountsRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Try this: `return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented))`. The `JsonConvert` object is in the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace, so you might need to add a reference and/or a using statement.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `WebApiConfig`.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

If you are still encountering the same exception, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12069484/6138713) and see if it helps.

> As it turned out, the error was caused by the fact that I had a
>   Microsoft Web API package installed from NuGet, which included
>   Json.NET. After uninstalling this, it works fine.
>
> This may be the answer for you - if not, look at which other packages
>   you have installed (that you don't need) and remove them.