# Can't import ServiceReference1 from ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

What `using` statements do I need to get at the `ServiceReference1` object in ASP.NET MVC4 application?

The `ServiceReference1` here is the name of my service reference that I added. What's weird, is that if I double click on it, it doesn't bring up anything in the object browser...

Update: For some reason "[Unchecking "Reuse types in referenced assemblies"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128845/74865)" solves my problem!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to your update, when you uncheck instead of all Reuse Types in referenced assemblies  just uncheck what you need.

Not sure if there's much more you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually investigating a completely different approach to services based on this video: http://dnrtv.com/dnrtvplayer/player.aspx?ShowNum=0122

Comment: Cool. Not a bad idea to take a step back from a problem sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that sometimes it gets confused if you have a namespace like `MyProject` and a service reference called `MyService`, but the code file that you're typing in is in something like `MyProject.AnotherNS`.  From that code file, you'd have to type `MyProject.MyService` to access the service, not just `MyService`.  The super-safe way to get this to always work is to use the `global` keyword, and type something like `global::MyProject.MyService`.  `global` just removes any implied prefix(es) from the namespace while in a block of code.