# Adding web services within an ASP .NET API

Tags: .net, api

I'm developing an ASP .NET API and I'd like to consume web services within this very API. 
I've successfully managed to include a new service reference by going to "Add service reference" in my ASP .NET API project. After all this is done, when I go to my controller, where my functions reside, intellisense doesn't seem to recognise my new service reference.

Any way my added reference can reflect within my project? 
Thanks.

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer to the question, rather than as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

After a painstaking day of endless googling and trial and error, I've managed to get my reference to reflect in my project. Go to "Add service reference" right click to bring up "Configure References" and uncheck "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" as shown in this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128845/1481289)